# How to manage color inheritance in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to override Bootstrap 5 `.text-success` `color` to have improved contrast on custom `.bg-lvlN` classes declared as follows:

```css
.bg-lvl1 {
  background-color: #303333;
}

.bg-lvl2 {
  background-color: #222424;
}

/* My attempt to override .text-success color */
.bg-lvl1 .text-success {
  color: #00d750 !important;
}

.bg-lvl2 .text-success {
  color: #00c74a !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-lvl2">
  <!-- This span has #00c74a color as expected -->
  <span class="text-success">Green</span>
  <div class="bg-lvl1">
    <!-- This span has #00c74a color but I would like it to be #00d750 -->
    <span class="text-success" id="nested">Green</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, `.bg-lvl2 .text-success` wins against the `.bg-lvl1 .text-success` rule on the `#nested` `span`.

Is there a way to make `.bg-lvl1 .text-success` apply to `#nested` `span` instead? Or a different way to proceed to get the desired color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this priority issue by redefining Bootstrap 5 `--bs-[color]-rgb` CSS variables on my custom background classes:

```scss
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';

.bg-lvl1 {
  --bs-success-rgb: to-rgb(#00d750);
}

.bg-lvl2 {
  --bs-success-rgb: to-rgb(#00c74a);
}
```

So that the following Bootstrap 5 `.text-success` rule is used and not overridden:

```css
.text-success {
  --bs-text-opacity:  1;
  color: rgba(var(--bs-success-rgb), var(--bs-text-opacity)) !important;
}
```

```css
.bg-lvl1 {
  background-color: #303333;
  --bs-success-rgb:  0, 170, 12;
}

.bg-lvl2 {
  background-color: #222424;
  --bs-success-rgb:  0, 158, 11;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-lvl2">
  <!-- This span has #00c74a color as expected -->
  <span class="text-success">Green</span>
  <div class="bg-lvl1">
    <!-- This span has #00d750 color as expected -->
    <span class="text-success" id="nested">Green</span>
  </div>
</div>
```